# What term would you use to indicate a maiden name you weren't born with?

Tags: names

My adopted sister is married and took her husband's name. She includes her former last name (my last name) in parentheses on her work email. In this case, ***née*** wouldn't be an accurate designation (although it would be practical).

Is there a term/word meaning *'name I had previously'* that doesn't indicate *'I was born with this name'*?

For clarity:

- *née* Jane Yu
- (grew up as) Jane Smith
- (Current name) Jane Naik
- Name as on office email: ***Jane Naik (_?_ Smith)***

**To be clear, I am not confused about the fact that née could be used correctly in this situation. I am asking whether there is an alternate term that doesn't literally mean "born" that could be used in short form, such as the email example I gave above.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32307/discussion-on-question-by-buildsucceeded-what-term-would-you-use-to-indicate-a-m).

Answer (score 19):

Consider, ***formerly***.

> in time past; in an earlier period or age; previously. [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formerly)
>
> *Jane Miller formerly Smith* [WikiTree](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Smith-73890)

Answer (score 6):

Consider **previously**:

> Debra Trent (previously Smith)

([LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/debra-trent-previously-smith-3a3a13a4))

> previously: at an earlier time or formerly

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=previously&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=))

Comment: Interesting. Perfect example of evolution of meaning, that (since "née" _literally_ means "born", at least in the original French).