# How do I properly write a decesed female name that was married twice?

Tags: grammaticality

Lavalle E. Thielker was married to a Lester M. Arentz and he died and then she married a Thielker.  Her maiden name is Lueck.  Is this the correct way to show her whole name?

Lavalle E. Arentz-*Lueck* Thielker 
or
Lavalle E Lueck-Arentz Thielker

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/q/287271/105642

Answer (score 3):

Lavalle E. Thielker (formerly Arentz, née Lueck).